Leibnitz rule and derivation of $d(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})$
I'm unable to derive this formula in the snippet below:
$d(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})$
What I've tried is this
$$d({f(x)}{g(x)}^{-1})=f(x)d(g(x)^{-1})+g(x)^{-1}d(f(x))$$
but now I've got stuck.Any hint?


Try rewriting $g^{-1}(x)$ as $h(g(x))$ with $h(x) = \frac 1x$.

Try not to open the spoilers immediately! It will be a good exercise to try it yourself first.
Note that $g(x)^{-1} = h(g(x))$ where $h(x) = x^{-1}$. Then, by the chain rule we obtain:
$$d(h\circ g (x))= dh(g(x)) dg(x).$$
Now, what is the derivative of $h(x)$?

 $$dh(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Then putting everything together you obtain:

 $$d(f (x)h\circ g (x)) = f(x)d(h\circ g(x)) + h\circ g(x)df(x) = -\frac{f(x)dg(x)}{g(x)^2} + \frac{df(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{df(x)g(x)- f(x)dg(x)}{g(x)^2}.$$


Generally you have $\text d(f(x))=f'(x)\,\text dx$.
Esp. for $h_n(x)=x^n$ one has $\text d(h_n(x))=\text d(x^n)=nx^{n-1}\,\text dx$ (mentioned in the book as Leibniz law).
Further you have the chain rule mentioned directly thereafter, i.e.
$$\text d(f(g(x)))=f'(g(x))\,g'(x)\,\text dx$$
Then it follows that
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\text d(f(x)g^{-1}(x)) & = &\text d(f(x))g^{-1}(x)+f(x)\text d(g^{-1}(x))\\
 & = & \text d(f(x))g^{-1}(x)+f(x)\text d((h\circ g)(x))\\
 & = & f'(x)\,g^{-1}(x)\,\text dx+f(x)\,h'(g(x))\,g'(x)\,\text dx\\
 & = & f'(x)\,g^{-1}(x)\,\text dx+f(x)\,\frac{-1}{g^2(x)}\,g'(x)\,\text dx\\
 & = & \frac{f'(x)\,g(x)-f(x)\,g'(x)}{g^2(x)}\,\text dx
\end{array}$$
